# Using for loop to remove movies from a list. For loop works once then throws index out of bounds exception

Tags: java, for-loop, tostring

for loop designed to remove movies from a movie list. Loop works successfully the first time but For loop throws out of bounds exception once a second movie is removed. Movie list contains 17 movies

I have tried changing values of size variable as well as decreasing the value of the size variable each time it loops.

```
public String toString(){
    StringBuilder returnString = new StringBuilder();

    int newSize = 16;

    for (int i = 0; i <newSize ; i++) {
        returnString.append(i+1).append("\n");
        returnString.append("Movie title: ")
                    .append(movieList.get(i).getTitle())
                    .append("\n");
        returnString.append("Lead Actor: ")
                    .append(movieList.get(i).getActor())
                    .append("\n");
        returnString.append("Release Year: ")
                    .append(movieList.get(i).getYear())
                    .append("\n");
        returnString.append("Genre: ")
                    .append(movieList.get(i).getGenre())
                    .append("\n");
    }

    return returnString.toString();
}
```

Comment: When you remove an item of list, the index has been changed, which causes Index Out of Bounds Exception.

Comment: Is there a way to have the newSize variable decreased by 1 when the loop is executed again?

Comment: @A.Cruz yes: `for (int i = movieList.size(); --i >= 0; )` (for instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are removing elements and continuing to iterate over the same list, you have to consider how data structures index their elements.

The problem with your code is, when you remove element 2, the 3rd element becomes the 2nd element. Because, when you remove an element from a list, all subsequent elements will shift to take its place. If you try to remove the penultimate element, you will get the exception. In order to get rid of this headache, try iterating the list backward.

```
for(int i = list.size(); i >= 0; i--) {
   // do stuff here, like removing
}
```

Comment: You are welcome! Make sure you mark the answer as correct by pressing the tick shaped button.

Answer (score 1):

If you iterate with an `Iterator`, you can also just call `iterator.remove()` to remove the current element and there is no need to index into the list:

```
public void removeOddValues(List<Integer> list) {
    for (Iterator<Integer> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
        Integer i = iter.next();
        if (i % 2 != 0) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Not all data structures have iterators that support `remove`, but `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` do.